# json schema for an array of items (referenced earlier in the schema)

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to come up with a schema for a json document that is , at the top level, an array of items. Each item describes a "git repo" we have with some mappings. Why is this failing?

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "$id": "http://i.am.awesome.com",
    "title": "title of the schema for our projects",
    "description": "description of the schema for our projects",
    "definitions": {
        "proj": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "visibility": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "private",
                        "public"
                    ]
                },
                "languages": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 2,
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "name",
                "visibility",
                "languages",
            ]
        }
    },
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/proj"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using python 3.8 with jsonschema and get this error

```
Failed validating 'anyOf' in metaschema['properties']['items']:
    {'anyOf': [{'$ref': '#'}, {'$ref': '#/definitions/schemaArray'}],
     'default': True}

On schema['items']:
    {'type': {'$ref': '#/definitions/proj'}}
```

What's interesting is that if I don't care for a list, and am schema checking a single element, simply having

`$ref": "#/definitions/proj`

So my referencing is correct,  just don't know why it doesn't work for a list of the same items.

Comment: Interesting that python jsonschema doesn't error on seeing an object under 'type' -- type can only have a string or array beneath it.

Comment: In retrospect, I think jsonschema is indeed seeing an error. It's just that the words it uses to print that error is not very obvious as to what is causing that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$ref` should be contained directly in the `items` keyword and not under `items.type`.
`type` is a reserved keyword that can only be a string or an array but not an object. That makes your schema invalid.

This would be a valid schema (omitting some details for readability):

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "proj": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    },
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/proj"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @carsten ! That fixed my issue. I was not aware that items can not point to a ref. Once removed it seems to accept the schema.

Comment: Well, as per the above example it can indeed point to a `$ref` like any other sub schema. The issue was in the wrong use of `type`.